# Decomposing an undirected graph into components with cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a standard definition of decomposing a graph a certain way. Suppose for example the graph looks like:

```
                           a-----b----c-----d
                                 |    |                              
                                 e----f-----i
                                      |     |
                                      g-----h----k
                                      |
                                      l
```

Then I would decompose the graph into 5 "components": a, (b,c,e,f,g,h,i),d,l,k.  Graphically this becomes:

```
a---(b,c,e,f,g,h,i)----d
         |     |
         l     k
```

The decomposition can be defined as recursively as:

```
1. We say a==b if there is a simple cycle containing a and b.

2. if a ==b and b == c then a==c.
```

So in the above graph b == f but also f == i , so b,f and i are in the same component.

Is there a standard definition for such a decomposition?

Comment: There is an algorithm that finds matchings in general graphs, made by Edmonds in 1965. The problem was that cycles of odd length could occur so he shrank them to a "supernode" exactly like you do. It only shrinks odd cycles so maybe its nothing usefull but it could give you some inspiration!

Comment: Its fairly easy to compute, however, I am looking for whether there is a standard definition for this. It would seem that there should be one.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected to remedy the error described by @danb's comments.

---

Your relation seems to be equivalent to

> $a == b$ when $a$ and $b$ are on some *simple* cycle.

Where a simple cycle is a closed sequence of distinct adjacent edges.

This is an equivalence relation (assuming it's reflexive), and the required decomposition is into its equivalence classes.

I've never seen this relation employed, but I don't know much :).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a and b on some cycle.  For example in the above graph a and f are in a cycle but it is not a simple cycle.

Comment: By a cycle I think you mean one with no overlapping edges.  Then yes I think you are correct

Comment: @danb You're right. The equivalence relation required is that of being on a *simple* cycle. Allowing any old cycle just produces connected components.